# How to use Group By for multiple case statements

Tags: group-by, case

I'm using Oracle Apex 21.2 on a 21.c database.
I have three tables that I use for a report of volunteers:
VOL_CONTACT
VOL_MINISTRY
VOL_CONTACT_MINISTRY

The VOL_CONTACT_MINISTRY table contains two foreign keys that equal the primary keys of VOL_CONTACT and VOL_MINISTRY.
I can execute the following SQL, but it produces multiple rows per contact, depending on how many ministries they're assigned.  Each row has only 1 "X" underneath the appropriate column.  I'm trying to get one row per contact, with simply an X underneath the columns where they're assigned to a given ministry.  I suspect I need to use a Group By clause, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it work for columns that are generated by a Case statement.
For Clarity, here's what the report looks like now:
[image: Report produced from the code above]
Here is what I'd like the report to look like:
[image: Desired Report]

```
select vc.prim_key,
       vc.last_name,
       vc.first_name,
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 13 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "ELL",
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 14 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "Health",
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 15 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "Finance",
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 16 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "Hospitality",
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 17 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "Publicity",
    Case when vcm.ministry_fkey = 18 
        and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.prim_key 
        Then 'X' else null
    End as "Education",
       vc.email_1,
       vc.email_2
  from VOL_CONTACT vc,
       VOL_CONTACT_MINISTRY vcm,
       VOL_MINISTRY vm
  where 
       vc.status = 'Active'
   and vm.ministry = 'Refugee'
   and vcm.contact_fkey = vc.PRIM_KEY
   and vcm.ministry_fkey = vm.PRIM_KEY
order by
       vc.last_name, vc.first_name
```